# Sort alphabetically ArrayList of Strings in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to sort an ArrayList of strings. So far I have tried using `ArrayList.sort` but I am note sure how to use it properly.

My class looks like this:

```
     ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        String value,value1,value2;
        value="String1";
        value1="String2";
        value3="String3";

        arraylist.add(value);
        arraylist.add(value1);
        arraylist.add(value2);
```

I have no idea how to sort this one. 
Last time when I was using ArrayList of custom objects like

```
ArrayList<myObject> = new ArrayList<>();
```

I implemented `Comparable` interface, then I overrode the `compareTo` method in myObject class and everything was...easier.

How do I sort with ArrayList using just simple Strings?

@Edit
Trying few things on my own, I've used `arraylist.sort(null)` and somehow it worked like it was supposed to. No more help is needed, thank you guys.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Well, thats wasnt good example. Lets make value=b,value1=a,value2=aa, and I'd like to see a,aa,b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sort()` of `ArrayList` only works if you are proving a Comparator.

For the `String` `Double` `Integer` you can use `Collection.sort()`. It directly modifies the arraylist you pass instead of returning a new arraylist.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        String value,value1,value2;
        value="C";
        value1="Z";
        value2="A";

        arraylist.add(value);
        arraylist.add(value1);
        arraylist.add(value2);
        System.out.println(arraylist);
        Collections.sort(arraylist);
        System.out.println(arraylist);
}
```

Comment: Tried this one in a first place since ArrayList.sort didn't work for me and all I've got was "Method call expected"

Comment: @BednarQ It's working fine for me. Can you please provide your whole code with `Collections.sort()`? With your imports,class,main().

Comment: I've tried `arrayList.sort(null)` and somehow it worked like it was expected to, so I think i dont need more help. Thank you anyway